# Is disabling AppArmor to solve permission issues when deploying MaaS advisable?

Tags: maas, apparmor

I'm still yet to successfully build a MAAS server, deploy nodes and charms with 12.04 LTS. In my latest troubleshooting in my logs, I have found several errors in my syslog pertaining to permissions issues with apparmor. Every time I would fix one, another would show up. I finally decided to disable apparmor with the following command:

```
ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.cobblerd /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.cobblerd
```

Do you see any problems with doing this? After apparmor was disabled, I was able to successfully run `sudo cobbler check` and got a message back saying *All systems go.*

Answer (score 1):

While it would be OK to disable the apparmor profile for maas-provision, I'd highly discourage it. The profile handles the operations that are needed for MAAS within cobbler, and while you might see denials, it continues to work the way MAAS needs cobbler to.

In other words, these apparmor permission errors are irrelevant to what you are doing.